# 'Unable to lock row' error when deploying changesets to PROD

Tags: deployment

I am facing with this weird problem while running test classes or performinh changeset deployment.Many of our tests involve creating Products and Pricebook Entries. In order to use a product in an opportunity or quote, it has to be in the Standard Pricebook. The problem occurs when our tests create products and add them to the Standard Pricebook. Even though we aren't directly editing the actual pricebook, inserting pricebook entry records touches the pricebook record and locks it. Then, when the next test tries to insert records it can't and we end up getting an "UNABLE_TO_LOCK_ROW" error. So Test A inserts pricebook entries, and when Test B tries to run at the same time and also tries to insert pricebook entries, we get an error.

In sandbox we usually disable parallel test execution, even though this causes our unit tests to take about an hour to run instead of about 15 minutes. However, we can't control how the tests are run when deploy a change set.

How can I get rid of this problem.

Comment: Are you using `@IsTest(SeeAllData=true)` still? With Summer `14 (v31.0) you can use Test.getStandardPricebookId(). I haven't tested it (hence the comment), but it might give you separate instances so the test cases don't try and work with the same record. See [Create Price Book Entries in Apex Tests](http://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer14/release-notes/rn_apex_price_books_in_tests.htm)

Comment: No I am not using @IsTest(SeeAllData=true)

Comment: OK. Good to know. Is parallel test execution already disabled in the Org you are deploying the change set to?

Comment: Yes but will it control the test class execution when deploying or when I do run all test ?

Comment: I always thought it did and haven't run into further issues (other than the time to complete the tests). However, I don't use change sets in my scenario.